# Makefile Packages in C

Tags: c, makefile

What packages do i need to install in order to use a Makefile. I've already installed cmake, would i need ocamlmakefile?
My problem is that whenever i type 'make' into the terminal, i'm told "make command not found".

Comment: Hm, such a question makes not much sense without telling us what OS, architecture, distribution whatever... you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need GNU make.

CMake and other make programs use other filenames generally.

Comment: It actually depends. There's quite many different dialects of make, if it's a complicated makefile that may matter. GNU make is a good start however, if it does not work, post a snippet from the makefile and see if anyone recognize the dialect.